# WSO2 API Manager with non-WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have a working system with `ESB` (non-WSO2 product) already. I'm now trying to integrate`WSO2 API Manager` into my working system for 3rd party developer.
Is it possible to replace `WSO2 ESB` in `API Manage` with existing `non-WSO2 ESB`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

The `ESB` functionality is transparent no matter what is the brand of underlying product implementing it. The API Manager is going to store the endpoints, WSDLs, etc. and those are the same for every ESB implementation.

That's the "beauty" of SOA, its service-oriented, not vendor-oriented.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the ESB you are using as it is in your setup and use the API Manager to publish/subscribe/manage the API. Its perfectly a valid scenario

Regards,
/Nuwan